# How to calculate memory allocated in rdkafka producer?

Tags: c, memory, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I want to implement some `Kafka` producers using `librdkafka` each one has huge traffic and many topics. Before that, I want to calculate how much `RAM` I need. I know that there are some options that affect this calculation like `queue.buffering.max.messages`, `queue.buffering.max.kbytes` and `message.max.bytes` and also the number of topics and partitions. So how can I calculate the allocated `RAM` or at least the maximum memory I need?